# Combine ocg and hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, ocg

Can I combine an ocg command and a hyperlink?  For instance, can I turn the following two commands on the second page into something that only takes one click to both return to the first page and toggle the ocg

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocgx2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\hypertarget{target}{Now it's} 
\begin{ocg}{Sidebar label}{ocglabel}{1} here \end{ocg}
\newpage

\switchocg{ocglabel}{Click here first to toggle ocg}
\hyperlink{target}{Then click here to go to page 1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple actions to be executed on clicking a link can be chained together thanks to the `/Next <<...>>` entry in the PDF Link annotation.

Unfortunately Evince doesn't seem to evaluate `/Next ...`. Thus, we are restricted to using Acrobat Reader. This should be reported as a bug or feature request to Evince developpers.

The example below defines a command for creating links that look like `hyperref` generated links and which combine OCG Toggle and GoTo actions, as requested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocgx2}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\toggleOCGGoTo[3]{
  \leavevmode
  \pbs_pdflink:nn{
    /Subtype/Link
    /A <<
      /S/SetOCGState
      /State [
        /Toggle~\tl_if_exist:cT{ocgx2.ocg.#1}{\tl_use:c{ocgx2.ocg.#1}}
      ]
      /Next << /S/GoTo/D~(#2) >>
    >>
    %look and feel of hyperref links, if hyperref has been loaded
    \cs_if_exist:NTF\Hy@setpdfborder{
      \Hy@setpdfborder\g_ocgxii_patch_tl
      \ifx\@pdfhighlight\@empty\else/H\@pdfhighlight\fi
      \ifx\@linkbordercolor\relax\else/C[\@linkbordercolor]\fi
      \ifHy@pdfa /F~4\fi
    }{
      /Border~[0~0~0]
    }
  }{
    \cs_if_exist:NTF\Hy@colorlink{
      \Hy@colorlink\@linkcolor#3\Hy@endcolorlink\Hy@VerboseLinkStop
    }{#3}
  }
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\hypertarget{target}{Now it's} 
\begin{ocg}{Sidebar label}{ocglabel}{1} here \end{ocg}
\newpage

\toggleOCGGoTo{ocglabel}{target}{Toggle OCG and go to target}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect.  I figured the PDF specification could handle it but no way was I confident about digging into it.